# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date “yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ” - SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android, sql

I am suffering error from this code

```
 java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1998-09-17T00:00:00.000+08:00" (at offset 23)
```

I not sure what wrong with the code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
          Date date = null;
          try
          {
              date = sdf.parse(startdate);
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
          SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
          String dateStr = formatter.format(date);

  System.out.println(dateStr);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timezone format is not correct.

The Timezone should be `+0800` not `+08:00`.

According to the samples in the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for `SimpleDateFormat`, you should be fine with

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"  -> 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00
```

`XXX` is the ISO Format, that will allow the colon in the timezone.

Comment: The timezone is auto generated, not written by me

Comment: It didn't work, it say  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'

Comment: This works for JDK7 and JDK8, at least. What Java version do you use?

Comment: i'm using "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" with JDK8 but still have error Unknown pattern character 'X'